# How to write a selenium code for this html tag?

Tags: html, selenium-webdriver

Can any one please tell me how to click on login "button" using selenium webdriver

```
Below is the login button's html snippet.

<button class="btn btn-success pull-right " value="submit" type="submit">
Login
<i class="m-icon-swapright m-icon-white"></i>
</button>
```

Comment: Can you tell us what research you've done so far?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am assuming you want to know about how to click the login button of your AUT by the way of selenium webdriver:

**Update after update in the question:**

Below is the way to login in your case:

```
    WebDriver driver=new FirefoxDriver();
    driver.findElement(By.xpath("//button[@class='btn btn-success pull-right ']")).click();
```

Comment: Ya im trying for login button, Can u tell me for this,                                     <button class="btn btn-success pull-right " value="submit" type="submit">
Login
<i class="m-icon-swapright m-icon-white"></i>
</button>